# Notation question for finite simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, notation

Looking at the article on finite simple groups in Wikipedia ("List of finite simple groups") it uses a notation for the order of the groups that I am not familiar with.  For example, the order of the Steinberg groups has a factor of $\frac{q^{(n(n-1))}}{(4, q^{n+1})}$. What is the meaning of the comma in the parenthesis in the denominator?

Comment: If you scroll up to the top of the section you are at (Groups of Lie type) then there is a paragraph labelled notation; this paragraph includes the definition of the notation $(a, b)$. As a side note, I really dislike the notation $(a, b)$ for gcd and I always use $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.